# Wait for multiple async tasks to complete

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdasync

I am kicking off several async tasks like so:

```
for(UINT Id: myIds)
{
    std::async([=]
    {
        DoSomeStuffUsingId(Id);               

        return true;
    });
}
```

I have a function that needs to know if all these tasks have completed:

```
void SomeFunction()
{ 
    if (all async tasks have completed)
    {
        do something else
    }
}
```

I understand that I can wait on an async task like so:

```
std::future<bool> fut = std::async (do something); 
fut.wait();
```

And I see from this link [Waiting for multiple futures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225372/waiting-for-multiple-futures) that there is no wait for multiple futures yet.

Is there any trick I can use to see if all my tasks have completed?

Could I store each future in an array or vector and wait on each one in turn?

Comment: One thing you could do is have each thread reference an atomic bool.  When the task is complete they can set it to true.  Then you know that that thread completed. This allows you to poll the variable without a wait command.

Comment: Have you tried storing each future in an array or vector and waiting for each? Sounds like a perfectly reasonable pattern to use.

Comment: Note that just calling std::async() is not enough to guarantee that all lambdas are run as asynchronous tasks, you need to specify std::launch::async to ensure that. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async

Answer (score 1):

you can use std::shared_future's (that can be copied) or vector::emplace_back() to emplace std::futures' that cannot be copied, but can be moved.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to solve this problem is to pass a `shared_ptr<collector>` to all the async functions. Let these async functions to call `collector::collect(...)` to pass its data to the collector. Once all the async functions return, the `collector` object will be deleted automatically. Now use the destructor `collector::~collector()` as a notification that all async functions have completed.