# Why is there no std::future::then in C++17?

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, standards, c++17

`boost::future` has a member function: `boost::future::then`, while `std::future` has no `std::future::then`.

This [wonderful article](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2014/02/26/c17-i-see-a-monad-in-your-future/) shows how useful `std::future::then` would be.

Why is there no `std::future::then` in C++17?

Is it just an oversight, or because of other rationale behind?

Comment: There was a proposal for this feature by Herb Sutter. I dont know if that has been excepted.

Comment: perhaps see this discussion - it could explain more :

http://stackoverflow.com/q/19225372/3990012

Comment: It looks like the future of futures is in question.  A thenable future may not be in scope for the standard and we may have to rely on other libraries like boost or folly: https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/a-short-detour-executors

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`.then` support was incorporated into the Concurrency TS, which was finalized in early 2016. There was little practical experience with implementations of Concurrency TS, and with little time remaining until C++17 needed to be feature complete, it didn't make it in. Indeed, it was so late they didn't even bother proposing to add it to C++17.

Comment: too sad, "continuation style" is very useful

Comment: why it wasn't added to C++20?

Comment: [C++20. Where is std::future::then() and the concurrency TS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63360248/5447906)