# Where is std::future::then() and the concurrency TS?

Tags: c++, c++20

When seaching for std::future::then on google, the top result is [a stackoverflow question about the status of the function in c++17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41310197/why-is-there-no-stdfuturethen-in-c17). Now that c++20 has been finalized and Clang and GCC is well into implementing c++20, I am left wondering what is the status of the function and the Concurrency TS generally?

It isn't mentioned on the implementation status page of [libc++](https://libcxx.llvm.org/cxx2a_status.html), [libstdc++](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2020) or [the implementation status page maintained by cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support)), and the [TS page on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/concurrency) doesn't say anything about current status.

I have also tried running some very simple examples on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/xoExna), but neither are able to find <experimental/future>, and not because it has been moved to the <future> header (neither can find future::then.

Additionally, the internet has not been especially helpful. At least I can only find [blog posts](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/the-end-of-the-detour-unified-futures) from 1-2 years ago talking about "hoping" to get the Concurrency TS in c++20, but cannot find any mentions in numerous overviews of new c++ 20 features ([a](https://github.com/AnthonyCalandra/modern-cpp-features) [few](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/20) [examples](https://hackaday.com/2019/07/30/c20-is-feature-complete-heres-what-changes-are-coming/%5D).

Has the Concurrency TS been dropped?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Has the Concurrency TS been dropped?

Yes.

[P1445](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1445r0.pdf) discusses this, SG1 voted to withdraw the TS. Note that atomic smart pointers, latches, and barriers *are* in C++20.

As far as improving `future` goes, the direction there is called *executors* and the design currently being iterated on is [P0443](https://wg21.link/p0443), which allows for lazy composition of work in a way that would be much more efficient than `future::then`. Two of the authors gave a talk on this at [CppCon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tF-Nz4aRWAM) that goes into the issues pretty well.

Comment: Oh damn, too bad. I was looking forward to a futurized architecture, like described in [This talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=js-e8xAMd1s) in standardized c++, but without .then and .when_all (and assosiated support for co_await), I suppose this will have to wait. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: so we don't have future::then in C++20 neither do executors in C++23...