# Does future in c++ corresponding to promise in javascript?

Tags: javascript, c++, functional-programming

I am a c++ programmer and tried to study `std::future` and `std::promise` these days. When I randomly search some information about future/promise, I found some [discussion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) about future/promise in javascript and promise in javascript has `then` function. In c++, even though `std::future` don't have `then` function now, but some [proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63360248/where-is-stdfuturethen-and-the-concurrency-ts) have mentioned it. So, there are two question:

1. does `std::future` in c++ corresponding to promise in javascript?
2. if 1 is true, why they confused future and promise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. `std::future<T>` stands for a future result of `T`, i.e. the object will at some point in *the future* hold a `T`. `std::promise<T>` is an object *promising to provide* a `T` at some point in the future.

Which language got the naming right is debatable.

Comment: "*Which language got the naming right is debatable.*" neither one. There isn't one single thing called "future" or "promise". It's more of a class of things - asynchronous results. Different places use the words differently - some times interchangeably, some times they define different meaning. And a promise in one place does not necessarily correspond to a promise in another. Same with futures. Same with futures-promises.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically-typed languages sometimes combine concepts that are separated in statically-typed languages. A JavaScript promise is basically both a C++ promise and future. The `resolve` and `reject` functions in JavaScript roughly correspond to the promise side in C++, and the `then` function in JavaScript roughly corresponds to the future side in C++.

`then` also can compose promises in JavaScript, which you might consider a third feature, but in practice futures aren't very useful without composition.

Comment: for `x`,  `std::async([](int x) {return x;})` just return a `future` whose value is `x`, does it same as `resovle`?