# Async calls in c++ ordered by completion

Tags: c++, asynchronous, order-of-execution

I am learning asynchronous programming in c++, consider the following code:

```
#include<iostream>       
#include<future>         
#include<chrono>
#include<thread>
#include<utility>
#include<string> 
#include<vector>


std::pair<int,std::string> check_even(int num){
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds((10-num)*100));
  if(num%2==0) return {num,"even"};
  return {num,"odd"};
}


int main(){
  std::vector<std::future<std::pair<int,std::string>>> ft;
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++) ft.push_back(std::async(check_even,i));

  for(auto& f : ft){
    auto rs = f.get();
    std::cout << rs.first << " is " << rs.second << '\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

That gives the following output:

```
0 is even
1 is odd
2 is even
3 is odd
4 is even
5 is odd
6 is even
7 is odd
8 is even
9 is odd
```

I understand why the output is like that, but the problem is that I don't want to get the results from the async calls in the order they were made, but in the order that they are done.

I did some research and I think that I need to use `std::experimental::when_any`, but I can't find much information about it; The [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/when_any) site is very bare-boned on this subject and the page hasn't been update in over 5 years, so I am not sure about it.

Is that it? If someone could do an example, I've been struggling to put in practice these concepts.

Comment: You forgot the first argument in the call to async, Use `std::async(std::launch::async, { [i]{ check_even(i); });` (second argument of async is a function, a lambda in this case). See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async example a3 = ...

Comment: not much you can do until the concurrency TS makes some progress. You might be better off using boost or other concurrency libraries. Boost has the advantage of potentially following the future standard library so if the concurrency TS ever happens you should be able to switch fairly easily

Comment: Note your program is doing what it should be doing see : https://onlinegdb.com/Uj8CaLCMh. As Alan said you are waiting on futures in the same order you created them.

Comment: @PepijnKramer yes, I understand that the code does what it is supposed to do, that is why I asked if using `when_any` would change the behaviour to what I wanted

Comment: @AlanBirtles I will check the boost library then, thank you. I was curious, because the thread that the moderators marked as a duplicate (I had already check it) is quite old and one of the anwsers talk about c++14 and I had no lucky with that, I guess they post poned it to a later revision?

Comment: It looks like updates to futures are abandoned and replaced with executors but those also haven't made it into c++23 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63360248/where-is-stdfuturethen-and-the-concurrency-ts

Comment: As an (std-only) alternative, you can also use active polling, something as: https://godbolt.org/z/44adz95z7.