# Single-threaded asynchronous code in C++17

Tags: c++, asynchronous, c++17, boost-asio, future

I am developing a kind of smart UDP/TCP proxy for a very limited device with embedded Linux. The device has a prescribed SDK, therefore i am limited to GCC C++17, can't use Clang or C++20. I have the basics running nicely using Boost 1.83 ASIO socket async_* methods. But at larger usage, the callback hell starts creeping out fast and it's tedious to keep it under the lid.

I am looking for an equivalent of future chaining along the [existing boost feature](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures.then) but without the threading. Interestingly, Boost 1.83 lists [coroutines in C++17 examples](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp17_examples.html), but it does not compile - and I would not expect it to, because the critical Boost internal symbol BOOST_ASIO_HAS_CO_AWAIT is not defined in my stack.

How I understand the examples from [Boost completion tokens documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/model/completion_tokens.html):

1. Passing lambda function (or equivalent bound function signature) is what i do now.
2. `use_future` was promising but I learned that `std::future`, contrary to Boost future, [does not have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41310197/why-is-there-no-stdfuturethen-in-c17) `then()`, but anyway i assume it is powered by a thread pool because it does not recognize any eventloop.
3. `co_await` (et al) I can't use in my stack.

I am aware that there are nice community implementations which exactly fit my expectations e.g., https://github.com/xhawk18/promise-cpp, but I prefer using as little external dependencies as possible