# Signaling main thread when std::future is ready to be retrieved

Tags: c++, asynchronous, future

I'm trying to understand the `std::async`, `std::future` system. What I don't quite understand is how you deal with running multiple async "tasks", and then, based on what returns first, second, etc, running some additional code.

Example: Let's say your main thread is in a simple loop. Now, based on user input, you run several functions via `std::async`, and save the futures in a `std::list`.

My issue is, how do I pass information back from the `std::async` function that can specify *which* future is complete?

My main thread is basically in a message loop, and what I need to do is have a function run by `std::async` be able to queue a message that somehow specifies which future is complete. The issue is that the function doesn't have access to the future.

Am I just missing something?

Here is some pseudo-code of what I'm trying to accomplish; extra points if there is a way to also have a way to have a way to make a call to "cancel" the request using a cancelation token.

```
class RequestA
{
public:
    int input1;

    int output1;
};

main()
{
    while(1)
    {
       //check for completion
       // i.e. pop next "message"
       if(auto *completed_task = get_next_completed_task())
       {
          completed_task->run_continuation();
       }

       // other code to handle user input
       if(userSaidRunA())
       {
          // note that I don't want to use a raw pointer but
          // am not sure how to use future for this
          RequestA *a = new RequestA();
          run(a, OnRequestTypeAComplete);
       }

    }
}

void OnRequestTypeAComplete(RequestA &req)
{
    // Do stuff with req, want access to inputs and output
}
```

Comment: You could pass callable to the executing thread that would put a message in the queue.

Comment: `std::async` operates on a `Callable` object. You could, for instance, assign an ID number to that object when you create it, and store that ID in the list with the `std::future` object. The `Callable` could then post its ID to the message queue and the message handler can look for the ID in the list. Another option would be to add an empty `std::future` to the list first, then pass an iterator to that object to the `Callable` so it can post it back to the message queue. Move the result of `std::async` to that existing `std::future` object, and have the message handler use the posted iterator

Comment: You may want to take a look at e.g. the HPX library (http://stellar-group.org/category/hpx/). The standard library currently does not have elegant solutions to these issues. In particular, HPX offers continuations for futures with ``then()``, and waiting for any of a whole range of futures with ``when_any()``/``wait_any()``.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately C++11 `std::future` doesn't provide continuations and cancellations. You can retrieve result from `std::future` only once. Moreover future returned from `std::async` blocks in its destructor. There is a group headed by Sean Parent from Adobe. They implemented [`future`](https://github.com/stlab/libraries/blob/develop/stlab/concurrency/future.hpp#L755), [`async`](https://github.com/stlab/libraries/blob/develop/stlab/concurrency/future.hpp#L1276), [`task`](https://github.com/stlab/libraries/blob/develop/stlab/concurrency/task.hpp) as it should be. Also functions with continuation like [`when_all`](https://github.com/stlab/libraries/blob/develop/stlab/concurrency/future.hpp#L956), [`when_any`](https://github.com/stlab/libraries/blob/develop/stlab/concurrency/future.hpp#L973). Could be it is what you're looking for. Anyway have a look at [this project](https://github.com/stlab/libraries/tree/develop/stlab/concurrency). Code has good quality and can be read easily.

If platform dependent solution are also ok for you you can check them. For windows I know [PPL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd492418.aspx) library. It also has primitives with cancellation and continuation.

Comment: The issue is that when_any doesn't help with the continuation or the cancellations. I've looked at PPL, and I don't think it really fits what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `struct` containing a flag and pass a reference to that flag to your thread function.

Something a bit like this:

```
int stuff(std::atomic_bool& complete, std::size_t id)
{
    std::cout << "starting: " << id << '\n';

    // do stuff
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(hol::random_number(3000)));

    // generate value
    int value = hol::random_number(30);

    // signal end
    complete = true;
    std::cout << "ended: " << id << " -> " << value << '\n';

    return value;
}

struct task
{
    std::future<int> fut;
    std::atomic_bool complete;

    task() = default;
    task(task&& t): fut(std::move(t.fut)), complete(t.complete.load()) {}
};

int main()
{
    // list of tasks
    std::vector<task> tasks;

    // reserve enough spaces so that nothing gets reallocated
    // as that would invalidate the references to the atomic_bools
    // needed to signal the end of a thread
    tasks.reserve(3);

    // create a new task
    tasks.emplace_back();

    // start it running
    tasks.back().fut = std::async(std::launch::async, stuff, std::ref(tasks.back().complete), tasks.size());

    tasks.emplace_back();
    tasks.back().fut = std::async(std::launch::async, stuff, std::ref(tasks.back().complete), tasks.size());

    tasks.emplace_back();
    tasks.back().fut = std::async(std::launch::async, stuff, std::ref(tasks.back().complete), tasks.size());

    // Keep going as long as any of the tasks is incomplete
    while(std::any_of(std::begin(tasks), std::end(tasks),
        [](auto& t){ return !t.complete.load(); }))
    {

        // do some parallel stuff
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
    }

    // process the results

    int sum = 0;
    for(auto&& t: tasks)
        sum += t.fut.get();

    std::cout << "sum: " << sum << '\n';
}
```

Comment: This isn't exactly what I'm trying to do. What I want to be able to do is identify which task completed without iterating through all of the tasks.

One of my ideas was to have the end of the async call enqueue a struct which has a continuation lamba, which could possibly contain some of the state of the "request"

Comment: @bpelkes I'm not sure the standard libraries can do that in a neat way, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225372/waiting-for-multiple-futures ,

Answer (score 2):

Here a solution with a `std::unordered_map` instead of a `std::list` in which you don't need to modify your [callable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Callable)s. Instead of that, you use a helper function that assigns an *id* to each *task* and notify when they finish:

```
class Tasks {
public:
    /*
     *  Helper to create the tasks in a safe way.
     *  lockTaskCreation is needed to guarantee newTask is (temporarilly)
     *  assigned before it is moved to the list of tasks
     */
    template <class R, class ...Args>
    void createNewTask(const std::function<R(Args...)>& f, Args... args) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lockTaskCreation(mutexTaskCreation);
        newTask = std::async(std::launch::async, executeAndNotify<R, Args...>,
            std::move(lock), f, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

private:
    /*
     *  Assign an id to the task, execute it, and notify when finishes
     */
    template <class R, class ...Args>
    static R executeAndNotify(std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock,
        const std::function<R(Args...)>& f, Args... args)
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lockTaskCreation(mutexTaskCreation);
            tasks[std::this_thread::get_id()] = std::move(newTask);
        }
        lock.unlock();
        Notifier notifier;
        return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    /*
     *  Class to notify when a task is completed (follows RAII)
     */
    class Notifier {
    public:
        ~Notifier() {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
            finishedTasks.push(std::this_thread::get_id());
            cv.notify_one();
        }
    };

    /*
     *  Wait for a finished task.
     *  This function needs to be called in an infinite loop
     */
    static void waitForFinishedTask() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
        cv.wait(lock, [] { return finishedTasks.size() || finish; });
        if (finishedTasks.size()) {
            auto threadId = finishedTasks.front();
            finishedTasks.pop();
            auto result = tasks.at(threadId).get();
            tasks.erase(threadId);
            std::cout << "task " << threadId
                << " returned: " << result << std::endl;
        }
    }

    static std::unordered_map<std::thread::id, std::future<int>> tasks;
    static std::mutex mutex;
    static std::mutex mutexTaskCreation;
    static std::queue<std::thread::id> finishedTasks;
    static std::condition_variable cv;
    static std::future<int> newTask;

    ...
};

...
```

Then, you can call an async task in this way:

```
int doSomething(int i) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
    return i;
}

int main() {
    Tasks tasks;
    tasks.createNewTask(std::function<decltype(doSomething)>(doSomething), 10);
    return 0;
}
```

---

[See a complete implementation run on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fa9aa2086101e061)