# C++ Wait in main thread for future without while(true)

Tags: c++, multithreading, future, blocking

### Question

I want to know if it is possible to wait in the main-Thread without any while(1)-loop.
I launch a few threads via `std::async()` and do calculation of numbers on each thread. After i start the threads i want to receive the results back. I do that with a `std::future<>.get()`.

### My problem

When i receive the result i call `std::future.get()`, which blocks the main thread until the calculation on the thread is done. This leads to some slower execution time, if one thread needs considerably more time then the following, where i could do some calculation with the finished results instead and then when the slowest thread is done i maybe have some some further calculation.

Is there a way to idle the main thread until ANY of the threads has finished running? I have thought of a callback function which wakes the main thread up, but i still don't know how to idle the main function without making it unresponsive for i.e. a second and not running a while(true) loop instead.

### Current code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>

uint64_t calc_factorial(int start, int number);

int main()
{
    uint64_t n = 1;

    //The user entered number 
    uint64_t number = 0;

    // get the user input
    printf("Enter number (uint64_t): ");
    scanf("%lu", &number);

    std::future<uint64_t> results[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        // push to different cores
        results[i] = std::async(std::launch::async, calc_factorial, i + 2, number);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        //retrieve result...I don't want to wait here if one threads needs more time than usual
        n *= results[i].get();
    }
    // print n or the time needed 
    return 0;
}
```

```
uint64_t calc_factorial(int start, int number)
{
    uint64_t n = 1;
    for (int i = start; i <= number; i+=4) n *= i;
    return n;
}
```

I prepared a code snippet which runs fine, I am using the [GMP Lib](https://gmplib.org/) for the big results, but the code runs with `uint64_t` instead if you enter small numbers.

#### Note

If you have compiled the GMP library for whatever reason on your PC already you could replace every `uint64_t` with `mpz_class`

Comment: You could use a condition variable to wake up the main thread once each of the futures is ready. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable

Comment: You seem to be looking for a standard library solution to the WaitForMultipleObjects any-signaled model from winapi (or similar model from other back-ends). That doesn't exist. You have to code your own.(caveat: I'm out of touch with the standard library concurrency module since c++14, so if something were added in C++20, ymmv).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Waiting for multiple futures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225372/waiting-for-multiple-futures)

Comment: @Quimby kind of, in the question itself. The approach with the thread save queue and the condition variable might be it. The answer to the question is too CPU hungry

Comment: What behavior do you want exactly, though, if one of the results isn't yet available? Can you explain what you'd want the program to do if one thread takes too long?

Comment: @JohnFilleau i don't want the program to stop and wait for one thread... the calculation has to be merged together and i want, if one thead is slow, the other results to get merged parallel.

Comment: BTW i looked into most of the suggested questions before submitting it and @Quimby s question didn't show up

Comment: I linked it because you the gathering task is not a bad idea, it could be implemented by condition variables to be more sleepy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd approach this somewhat differently.

Unless I have a fairly specific reason to do otherwise, I tend to approach most multithreaded code the same general way: use a (thread-safe) queue to transmit results. So create an instance of a thread-safe queue, and pass a reference to it to each of the threads that's doing to generate the data. The have whatever thread is going to collect the results grab them from the queue.

This makes it automatic (and trivial) that you create each result as it's produced, rather than getting stuck waiting for one after another has produced results.

Comment: I made a while loop and iterate over the future-array already, i didn't show this hear for complexity reasons, but like i said i don't like this approach.
Your answer seems to satisfy my needs :D

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do you handle failures in this case? A global flag? A special queue value?

Comment: @Quimby: Depends a bit in the type of processing involved, but in quite a few cases  return something like a `std::optional<Result>`.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be the cleanest solution.