# C++ Async multi-thread file parsing store results in vector

Tags: c++

I'm trying to speed up a file parser by using multi threading. I've created a function that reads and parses a json-file and returns a vector.

Now, to speed things up, i tried to use async, so i created a future vector to store the results. When each thread is finished (ran the parsing function), i would like to append the results to a vector that stores all the results.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <future>

std::vector<int> parsefilefunction(std::string filepath)
{
    std::vector<int> vec{1, 2, 3};
    return vec;
}

std::vector<std::string> s = {
    "file1.json",
    "file2.json",
    "file3.json",
    "file4.json",
    "file5.json"};

int main()
{

    std::vector<int> results2;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
    {
        std::future<std::vector<int>> results = std::async(std::launch::async, parsefilefunction, s[i]);
        results2.push_back(results); //this is not working, i already tried with move()
    }
}
```

It would be super cool if you can help me! Thank you!

Edit: Indeed, "is not woking" is a terrible question desciption!

Compiled with:
`c++ stackoverflow.cpp -std=c++14 -pthread`

Error message:

```
error: no matching member function for call to 'push_back'
        results2.push_back(results);
        ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/vector:713:36: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'std::future<std::vector<int>>' to 'const std::__vector_base<int, std::allocator<int>>::value_type' (aka 'const int') for 1st argument
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY void push_back(const_reference __x);
                                   ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/vector:716:36: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'std::future<std::vector<int>>' to 'std::vector<int>::value_type' (aka 'int') for 1st argument
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY void push_back(value_type&& __x);
```

Comment: *“speed up a file parser by using multi threading”* — before even checking the issue at hand, this claim is very fishy to me. What makes you think that would actually work?

Comment: Thank you for your response! I must say im very new to C++ so I really appreciate your question what makes me think it would work. The purpose of the program is to parse ~ 350 json files, all with the same format to R for further calculations. One file right now is parsed in ~ 0.006 seconds, which is already mind-blowing fast for me working mainly in R. The main Idea was, what if I could use multiple cores to read and parse maybe 4 files at a time, then append everything and send it all in on to my R session. I hope i could explain my thought process. Read, parse send to R is already done :-)

Comment: This might be possible if you can split the workload in large chunks (handing 4 batches of 90 files to 4 threads might cut it). If doing it one by one, it is harder to say. Remember that communication between threads has a non-negligible cost, and that reading from the disk is not parallel to begin with. — Okay with that being said, the issue is that `std::async` starts the task in the background and returns immediately. So the task is not yet done when you're on the next line. Typically you would want to start the aync tasks, then wait for them to complete, and then collect the results.

Comment: You need to _move_ `results` into the vector.

Comment: Trying to split the workload in chunks will be the next step! @ChrisMM yes, thats it! But how would i achieve this?  ```results2.emplace_back(move(results));```is not working

Comment: `is not working` isn't a terribly helpful problem description.  Please edit your question to show all error message(s) verbatim.

Comment: You're right, I edited the question!

Comment: Check [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) on how to use `future`s. Also, to achieve actual parallelism (yet avoid `fork()` bombs on large numbers of files), you need to (1) keep creating `future`s until a parallelism limit and (2) then create one new `future` for each `future` you `wait()` for + `get()` + dispose of. The second step is non-trivial to do efficiently [because the standard lacks a `poll()`-like feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19228992/8584929). (You can implement event-driven notifications, but that (kinda’) defeats the purpose of `future`s.)

Comment: I will study more about futures for sure! Thank you for the hints and links provided! The accepted answer is working so far and runs about 3-4 times faster already for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to store `int`s in your `vector`, but have a `std::future`, that is not going to work. You have to get the `vector` out of the `future` and then copy its elements.

But with that approach you would have no async operation, since you always wait for the single operation to finish before you start the next one.

Here is an updated version which compiles: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/jE171j7GG

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <future>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> parsefilefunction(std::string filepath)
{
    std::vector<int> vec{1, 2, 3};
    return vec;
}

std::vector<std::string> s = {
    "file1.json",
    "file2.json",
    "file3.json",
    "file4.json",
    "file5.json"};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::future<std::vector<int>>> futures;
    std::vector<int> results2;

    for (const auto& file : s)
    {
        //Start async operations
        futures.emplace_back(std::async(std::launch::async, parsefilefunction, file));
    }

    for (auto& future : futures)
    {
        //Merge results of the async operations
        auto result = future.get();
        std::copy(result.begin(), result.end(), std::back_inserter(results2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, that was exactly what I was hoping for! Even though you warned there will be no asynchronous operation, the code is running ~3-4x faster. Can you imagine why?

Comment: Oh no, you misunderstood. With only one loop there would be no async. That's why there are two loops, first start the async operations and only then wait for them.

Comment: I see! Thank you, it's working like a charm and super fast! I expanded the program and now i face another problem, I would be so happy if you can give me the answer: result is now a struct, that contains a few vectors and a vector of vectors (ex. 1 vector that holds 3 vectors). If i use std::copy on that vector of vectors, the vectors will be added on that one holding the others (ex. 1 vector that holds 6 vectors). What would you do to force the vector to stay 1 vector that holds 3 vectors where each future will be appended to?
Even if u dont answer in this comment:: THANK YOU! C++ is awesome

Comment: After posting this comment here I just found my mistake: I forgot to populate the first vector with vectors, so i could not access it with [] notation...

Comment: If your value_type is also a vector, I recommend std::move instead of std::copy: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move